# Regex into variables

Tags: python, regex

I use a [regex101.com#python](http://regex101.com#python) and here are my strings:

Regular Expression:

```
.* src=.(?<Pvar1>\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}).* dst=.(?<Pvar2>\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})
```

Test String:

```
k=57829.57892gfjhfg.tur90eunn 4538.333.3 user="JHenry" src="10.10.1.21" dst="10.10.20.42" ttubbies="yellow"]
```

I try to transpose this to my code, but I have no clue on how to do this. How do I get `var1` and `var2` in Python and print them?

I tried `print(var1)` without any success.

Comment: What is `<Pvar1>` supposed to do? I don't see that in the test string.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 It's a named capture group.

Comment: `re.search`, or `re.match`.

Comment: Ah; I've never seen that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this.

```
import re
string = 'k=57829.57892gfjhfg.tur90eunn 4538.333.3 user="JHenry" src="10.10.1.21" dst="10.10.20.42" ttubbies="yellow"]'
results = re.match(".* src=.(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}).* dst=.(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})", string)
print results.group(1)
print results.group(2)
```

Example output:

```
$ python t.py
10.10.1.21
10.10.20.42
```

Answer (score 4):

Capture groups are accessed using the `group()` method of the `Match` object that `re.match` returns. If you use normal capture groups, the argument is the group number; if you use named capture groups the argument is the name.

```
str = 'k=57829.57892gfjhfg.tur90eunn 4538.333.3 user="JHenry" src="10.10.1.21" dst="10.10.20.42" ttubbies="yellow"]'
regexp = r'.* src=.(?<Pvar1>\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}).* dst=.(?<Pvar2>\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})'
match = re.match(regexp, str)
pvar1 = match.group('Pvar1')
pvar2 = match.group('Pvar2')
```

See the documentation of [Match objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects).